# trouble in call a ajax file in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This below coding is working in chrome browser but not in mozilla. How to solve this problem in mozilla firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#del_enquiry").click(function() {

        var enquiry = new Array();
            $('input[name="del_enq"]:checked').each(function() {
            enquiry.push(this.value);
        });
        if(confirm("Do you want to delete the Records"))
        {
            var delid="deleteid="+enquiry;
            $.ajax({
                 url: "delete_enquiry.php",
                 type: "POST",
                 data: delid,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(data) {
                        if(data==1) { 
                           alert("Record Deleted Successfully"); 
                        } else { 
                           alert("Record not Deleted"); 
                       }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is not working ? what error are you getting?

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: @user3797241,Put error function in ajax request & check errors on the Firefox.

Comment: Nothing displayed, Just Page will get refreshed.

Comment: check it in firebug addon. Console will show you java script errors.

Comment: Try putting `return false;` at the end of click even handler function. It will prevent page refresh, if there is no other error with your script.

Comment: I don't think the problem is on your javascript. Can you put your HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onsubmit atttribue of form tag function before submitting the form.
    
Inside my function write your confirm box conditions.
    if(confirm("Do you want to delete?"))
    {
        return true;
    }